# Is there an alternative to using a directive to create template code?

Tags: angularjs

I had HTML that was duplicated on many screens so I created a directive like this:

```
app.directive('adminRetrieveButton', ['stateService', function (stateService) {
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        template: "<button id='retrieveButton'\
                           ng-disabled='!home.forms.grid.$pristine'\
                           ng-click='ctrl.retrieve()' >Retrieve\
                      <span class='fa fa-fw mlr75'\
                         ng-class='{\"fa-spin fa-spinner\": stateService.action[Network.Retrieve], \"fa-download\": !stateService.action[Network.Retrieve] }' >\
                      </span>\
                   </button>",
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.stateService = stateService;
        }
    };
}]);
```

The directive and other similar ones has no functionality other than to create some template type of code.  Now rather than having to code in 8 lines of HTML in each page I just have one line:

```
<admin-retrieve-button></admin-retrieve-button>
```

Is there another alternative to this that would make it even simpler without my needing to create a directive?

Answer (score 1):

yes you dont need to create directive only for template you can simply use [ng-include](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude)

Directives are a powerful tool for working with and modifying the DOM, If you dont manipulating with DOM you dont need directive

Comment: ng-include isn't really appropriate for a control like this.

Comment: @GregoryAvery-Weir he wrote 'The directive and other similar ones has no functionality other than to create some template type of code. ' thats mean you dont need to create directive , and I think its not reasonable to downvote :)

Comment: Given that Marilou is injecting a service and that the directive is dependent on some scope data, ng-include is going to be more fragile. I also don't think that ng-include is "simpler" than using a custom directive. See http://www.linkedin.com/groups/nginclude-vs-directive-4896676.S.269608228 and https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/angular/0n7y4R0azDE for further discussion by others on this topic.

Comment: I've reviewed the rules for downvoting and agree that this is not "clearly and perhaps dangerously incorrect." I've removed my downvote.

Answer (score 0):

**There are alternatives, but your method is the best.** The way you have it is the correct Angular Way; if you have a standard control, make it a directive.

If you like, you can use the [templateUrl](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#template-expanding-directive) option to include the HTML in a separate file instead of inline in the directive configuration:

```
app.directive('adminRetrieveButton', ['stateService', function (stateService) {
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        templateUrl: "adminButton.html",
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.stateService = stateService;
        }
    };
}]);
```

...and in adminButton.html:

```
<button id="retrieveButton"
        ng-disabled="!home.forms.grid.$pristine"
        ng-click="ctrl.retrieve()" >Retrieve
    <span class="fa fa-fw mlr75"
            ng-class="{'fa-spin fa-spinner': stateService.action[Network.Retrieve],
                       'fa-download': !stateService.action[Network.Retrieve]}">
    </span>
</button>
```

This directive can access its parent scope because it has not been set to isolate scope; if you included a "scope" option on the directive call you'd need to pass in the `home` and `ctrl` variables.

You can use ng-include to do this, but your view code will look less semantic and injecting stateService will be a bit more complicated.

Comment: Can you give me an example of how I could use templateUrl in this example.  Would the code for the template be loaded when the directive is first created or when it's first used?

Comment: I believe that the template html is loaded when the directive is first displayed, but I'm not positive.